# Repeatedly Executed java Application freeze after some iteration

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Trying to make sense on the following code

When I executed one time it worked

```
ScimarkTestable sc = new ScimarkTestable(0.5,0.5);
sc.run();
```

But when I try to run multiple times like this it hangs:

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    ScimarkTestable sc= new ScimarkTestable(0.5,0.5);
    sc.run();
}
```

Any suggestion? I have tried many possibility including explicitly calling the garbage collector using

```
 System.gc()
```

Comment: What is `ScimarkTestable`?

Comment: Its  a Class I Created for Instrumentation purpose . The problem is when I run it in  a loop it hang else its ok

Comment: Maybe your `ScimarkTestable` objects are accessing the same resource in a not ``sinchronize`d manner: in this case the thread may block

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no possibilities for a [deadlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) in your code in `ScimarkTestable`.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly calling `System.gc()` is not going to help as it is just a request to JVM.

There could be 2 possible scenarios here -

1) The program has a large memory foot print and causes frequent 'stop-the-world' GCs. Check if this is the case by looking at the memory stats of your program (heap usage, perm-gen being full, memory allocated to your program etc.)

2) If the program starts multiple threads then there could be liveness issues (deadlock, starvation/livelock).